# Cannot override execution.iterations in taurus

Tags: blazemeter, taurus

This is my config that I'm trying to override by cli:

```
execution:
- concurrency: 1
  iterations: 20
  hold-for: 0s
  ramp-up: 0s
  scenario: delete

scenarios:
  delete:
    ...
```

When I try `bzt ./myconfig.yml -o execution.iterations=100`, I'm getting the following error

```
14:25:35 ERROR: Failed to apply override execution.iterations=100
14:25:35 ERROR: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I have also tried quoting it, ie. `"100"`, adding decimals, ie `100.0`,all  of them returned the same error. What is the correct way to override ints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to specify the particular (first?) execution. This is what we do for similar parameters:

```
...
-o execution.0.concurrency=${concurrency} \
-o execution.0.hold-for=${holdfor} \
-o execution.0.ramp-up=${rampup} \
...
```

You likely need to do the same for iterations:

```
-o execution.0.iterations=100
```

Comment: Thank you @user2762956, that worked! Wish they would clarify that in the documentations.